# Use of bool in Django QuerySet

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

When I have a QuerySet that may be empty, and is OK to be empty, I usually do:

```
results = MyModel.objects.filter(something)
if results:
    work on results
```

Is the conditional automatically translated to `bool(results)`, or is different to explicitly call `bool()` on QuerySets?

Thanks

*Note: I'm on Django 1.10 with Python 3.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same.

When doing `if obj`, `bool(obj)` is called, no matter what `obj`'s type is.

See this contrived example:

```
class A(list):
    def __bool__(self):
        print('called bool')
        return bool(super())

if A():
    pass

>> 'called bool'
```